# how to determine type of grammars looking at them

Tags: grammar

Suppose a grammar is given like this:

```
AB  →   CD
CD  →   CE
C   →   aC
C   →   b
bE  →   bc
```

what is a trick to find either it is type 0,1,2, or 3 grammar?

Comment: The Chomsky hierarchy is described on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy along with the restrictions on left- and right-hand sides of productions, which *might* be what you're looking for.